# Sublime Text 3 File Sync (connection manager)

Tags: aptana, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Recently I've moved from Aptana to Sublime Text 3. In Aptana there was a nice connection manager which allowed me to connect my local files to a different Drive, and I could then upload my local changes to that Drive.

I'm wondering if there is anything like that for Sublime. I can't find anything at the moment. It would also be ideal to have one where I upload the file myself (not done automatically).

Something like the sublime SFTP package, but runs with two local directories.

Any help is appreciated.